# Could not resolve all files for configuration: ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am attempting to implement a third party SDK bundle when I ran `react-native run-android` I got the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> > Could not resolve com.ts.auth-control-sdk:5.1.1.
> > Required by:
> > project :app

> ```
>   > Could not resolve com.ts:auth-control-sdk:5.1.1.
> ```

> ```
>     > Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/ts/auth-control-sdk/5.1.1/auth-control-sdk-5.1.1.pom'.
> ```

> ```
>       > Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/ts/auth-control-sdk/5.1.1/auth-control-sdk-5.1.1.pom'.
> ```

> ```
>         > sun.security.validator.Validator.Exception: PKIX path building failed:
> ```
>
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Inside of my `app/build.gradle` file, I have the following setup:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "com.ts:auth-control-sdk:5.1.1:arr"
  ...
}
```

Inside my `android/build.gradle` file I have the following:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven {
      url("$rootDir/../com/ts/auth-control-sdk/5.1.1")
    }

    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

I am not even sure whether this third-party SDK even exists inside of Jitpack repository.

Did I err in the way I implemented the dependency?

As far as the `maven` directory, per the documentation I placed a folder called `com/` inside the root folder of the mobile app and the folder structure of it is: **com > ts > auth-control-sdk > 5.1.1**

It seems as though if it's inside of `maven {}` it will go to Jitpack repo and look for library as opposed to just going to the root folder of the project. Am I correct in this conclusion?

By the way I placed it inside of `maven {}` because their documentation says to do so.

Could it be that `$rootDir` is what indicates to `maven` to go look at Jitpack since below all the libraries there is that:

`maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }`

Am I correct in concluding that `$rootDir` is referencing that jitpack url and not the root directory of the application?

Well, I gave it a shot and came away with the same exact error.

I believe I am correctly notating the file in accordance with this documentation:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html

I am not notating it like so: `implementation ("com.ts:auth-control-sdk-5.1.1@arr") { transitive=true }`

and removed the following : `maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }`

But then I get this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>
> > Could not resolve all the files for configuration 'app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> > Could not find com.ts:auth-control-sdk-5.1.1:.
> > Required by
> > project :app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me was inside of `android/build.gradle`:

```
maven {
  url("$rootDir/..")
}
```

I also removed:

```
maven {
  url { www.jitpack.io/ }
}
```

So that it would not keep going to the Jitpack repo to look for that local directory.

Then inside of `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation('com.ts:auth-control-sdk:5.1.1@aar') { transitive=true }
}
```

Comment: This worked.  Just removed the maven part.

Answer (score 3):

```
**go to your setting.gradle and write the below line of code for the the control 
       of 
  libraries or dependencies **
     
     maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }




      dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}
rootProject.name = "Xyz"
include ':app'

Answer (score -2):

If you have facing Gradle dependencies iss> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpsXX.png)

> FAILURE: Build completed with 6 failures.
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. Execution
> failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'. Execution failed
> for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Execution failed for task
> ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. Execution failed for task
> ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. Execution failed for task
> ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.ue

in android studio?

**Answer:**
If you using **ANDROID 11** in your project then try the below options
**Go to settings
Click option to Gradle, Execution, deployment
Then click build Tools
[Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lrms.png)
choose to gradle**

**Then disable the offline mode then Run**